# How to fix blurry texture on side of mesh? I'm following Blender Guru's couch tutorial

Tags: texturing

I tried unwrapping it again, to make sure that I actually unwrapped it and didn't forget. There was still this issue. Any solutions?[image]

Comment: have you tried just rotating that part of the UV map?  I have followed his tutorial in the past, and I encountered a very similar problem, but rotating the UV fixed it for me.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. I still looks the same.

Comment: please pack your images and share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/